# Filter rows from csv which have at max one empty column using Java Stream 8, filters and lambda

Tags: java, data-structures, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a csv file with the following format:

```
    columnA            ColumnB ColumnC   ColumnD   ColumnE ColumnF
 1)                     ABCXYZ    1       123.5     LMN     R
 2)  08/10/2017 09:07             2       218.81            K
 3)  08/10/2017 09:07   YWYI      2       218.81    PQR     K
```

I want to use Java 8 filters/lambda expressions to read this file and to accept rows which have values in COlumnB through ColumnF.

The filter should return two rows (1st and 3rd) for above file. (It does not matter if ColumnA is empty or not).

Comment: Pls post your code and running logs about your code

Comment: Ankit - you can and should write code which attempts to solve you problem. Like @Cyrus asked you - show SO that you are making an effort to research your problem and develop a solution for it, and you will get both respect and help.

Comment: It has less to do with java 8 and more to do with you are able to convert the csv to an array or another type of object and then just check for each value in the row for given constraints. Once you get the matching object collected in a data structure of your choice just convert it back to csv. Or readline split on csv separator and check manually. But this question should be closed for sure.